# correct way to use oracle reader?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, c#-4.0, oracle11g

11GR2 ......I want to get Alter statement for each table and run the result script to make two table same. But my result comes like below how can I make each Alter statement end with ; semicolon and looks like my result? I think problem is making alter statement for each table and putting terminator after each table, it is not putting each of the alter statement ; semi column terminator  ... Any idea?

***Mycode:***

```
myCommand = "select DBMS_METADATA_DIFF.COMPARE_ALTER('TABLE','GM_X','GM_X','SCOTT','GARY') from dual";

    using (OracleCommand Command = new OracleCommand(myCommand, conn1))
   {
     using (OracleDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
   {
     reader.Read();
     string[] split = reader[0].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 foreach (string line in split)
   {
      RichTextBox1.AppendText(reader[0].ToString().Trim() + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
   }
```

***result;***

```
ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_1" MODIFY ("INVH" VARCHAR2(15));
ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_2" MODIFY ("REODE" VARCHAR2(15));
ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("CUST" NOT NULL ENABLE)
  ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("CODE" VARCHAR2(14))
  ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("CODE" NOT NULL ENABLE)
  ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("E_CODE" NOT NULL ENABLE)
  ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("_GR2" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

***I want this result:***

```
 ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_1" MODIFY ("INVH" VARCHAR2(15));
    ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_2" MODIFY ("REODE" VARCHAR2(15));
    ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("CUST" NOT NULL ENABLE);
      ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("CODE" VARCHAR2(14));
      ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("CODE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
      ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("E_CODE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
      ALTER TABLE " TABLE_NAME_3" MODIFY ("_GR2" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach you want to iterate through each `split` element with a string called `line`. Your code doesn't do that:

```
   foreach (string line in split)
   {
      RichTextBox1.AppendText(reader[0].ToString().Trim() + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
   }
```

You're not using the line you've just gotten from split in each iteration. You want this:

```
   foreach (string line in split)
   {
      RichTextBox1.AppendText(line + ";" + Environment.NewLine);
   }
```

You don't even need to iterate through the line elements if you just replace `\n` with `;\n`.

```
string alterTableStatements = reader[0].ToString().Trim().Replace("\n", ";\n");
```